# Exactly synchronize AudioRecord and AudioTrack in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording, java-audio

I am trying to

- 1. Record PCM data using AudioRecord and save them to a .wav file. (Done)
- 2. Later on record another PCM file while playing the previously recorded file
- 3. Save the new recording to another file
- 4. Mix (overlay) the first and the new recording.

My problem is that the second recorded file (2.) and the first recorded file (1.) are not synchronous. Once I mix them together I hear a delay that I did not record. To test my app, I said 'Test 1 2 3' into the microphone. In the second recording I said 'Test 1 2 3' at the same time. However after mixing (overlaying) my 2 files, I get a delay.

What did I do wrong?

```
final Thread recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                final int SAMPLING_RATE = 44100;
                final int AUDIO_SOURCE = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
                final int CHANNEL_IN_CONFIG = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
                final int AUDIO_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
                final int BUFFER_SIZE = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLING_RATE, CHANNEL_IN_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT);
                final String AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME = project.getPath()+"/track"+String.valueOf(project.getTrackNumber())+".raw";
                final int playbackBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLING_RATE, CHANNEL_IN_CONFIG, AUDIO_FORMAT);


                @Override
                public void run() {
                    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
                    Log.d("Record", "[Starting recording]");

                    byte audioData[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                    boolean playSound = true;

                    ByteArrayOutputStream playbackOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream in = null;
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(project.getPath()+"/output.wav"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        playSound = false;
                    }

                    int playbackRead = 1;
                    byte[] playbackBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AUDIO_SOURCE,
                            SAMPLING_RATE, CHANNEL_IN_CONFIG,
                            AUDIO_FORMAT, BUFFER_SIZE);

                    AudioTrack player = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLING_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AUDIO_FORMAT, playbackBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                    player.play();

                    recorder.startRecording();
                    String filePath = AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME;
                    BufferedOutputStream os = null;
                    try {
                        os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.e("Record", "File not found for recording ", e);
                    }

                    while (!mStop) {

                        int status = recorder.read(audioData, 0, audioData.length);

                        if (status == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION ||
                                status == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                            Log.e("Record", "Error reading audio data!");
                            return;
                        }

                        try {


                            os.write(audioData, 0, audioData.length);
                            if (playSound) {
                                try {
                                    if (playbackRead > 0) {
                                        playbackRead = in.read(playbackBuffer);
                                    }
                                    if (playbackRead > 0){
                                        player.write(playbackBuffer, 0, playbackBuffer.length);
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("Record", "Error saving recording ", e);
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    try {
                        os.close();

                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.release();
                        player.stop();
                        player.release();

                        Log.v("Record", "Recording done…");
                        mStop = false;
                        File out = new File(project.getPath()+"/output.wav");
                        if (!out.exists()) {
                            out.createNewFile();
                            SoundUtils.rawToWave(new File(AUDIO_RECORDING_FILE_NAME), out, SAMPLING_RATE);
                        } else {
                            mixSound(project.getPath()+"/track1.raw", project.getPath()+"/track2.raw", project.getPath()+"/track3.raw", project.getPath()+"/track4.raw");
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Record", "Error when releasing", e);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Explanation:

- Running in a thread
- Creating AudioTrack and AudioRecord with the same settings
- boolean playSound: true if the first recording is already done and the wav is available
- in the loop:

  - Read the recorder audio data and write them to the output stream
  - Read a part of the previously recorded wav and write it to the player

(- Once there is nothing to play anymore, playbackRead is -1)

After that I try to mix my recordings. However my second recording is having a delay which I did not record.

What am I doing wrong? How do I (almost) completely correctly synchronize AudioRecord and AudioTrack so that when I say something it is played back at the position of the background recording as it was when I recorded it?

Comment: Is it acutally possible?

Comment: What about sending out a frequency over a certain period of time and detect the delay of the recording when post-processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a very exect solution and I would like to share it with everyone facing this problem in the future. I printed out every `short` value of the pcm data I was recording. It looked like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0.0025, 0.0026, 0.0163, 0.0123, ...
```

As you can see, there are many zero's at the beginning of the recording. But in a normal quite environment there is always a (very quite) noise in the background. It can't be exactly 0.

I thought, that maybe, this range, where all the 0's are is the time from the start of the recording till the first sound acutally receives the file.

=> **This is the delay**

In the second recording (while playing the previous recording as a background sound) I removed the starting 0's from the whole data so that the sound starts immediately. I then mixed both recordings together and they are very exactly synchronized.

I do not know whether this is a way how the delay could be removed in all situations but I tried it on several phones and it worked well. I am happy that I was able to solve my problem.

Long story short:  To remove the delay, remove all the 0's that are **in the front** of your sound data.

Comment: how did u print out the short value from byte buffer array

Comment: It's so long ago that I don't remember anymore. But I think after the line `os.write(audioData...)` you can just use `Log.d("YourTagNameHere", audioData)` . Hope it helps.